# Hiding angularjs attribute in html output

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let's say I have an angular directive for displaying media files (images & videos). It could look like this:

```
<div my-media mediatype="MediaFile.Type" mediapath="MediaFile.Path"></div>
```

Is it possible to hide that directive's attribute in html output? Or at least it's value.

For example, I have a similiar directive which is repeated with ng-repeat and it's "mediapath" is base64 code from html input files. Those paths greatly increase size of html and it is very hard to modify that kind of code. Also browser always freezes when inspecting such an element.

Comment: Is there a reason the HTML needs to have the information? In your ng-repeat example, is it possible to just have a JavaScript object with a "mediapath" property? If you using that path for a link or some other type of navigation, you could always pass the value from your view into your controller, and do your navigation in code using the $location service... but if you need the value for something like an image... I think  you are stuck with it in your HTML

Comment: Yes, I am using that value to append either img or video element. Path is $watched in that directive, because it could be empty (Path value gets assigned from file reader directive only if it's size is small enough (I would not want to display image that is 20mb large)). Getting the right path from javascript object would be a mess. So, yes I guess I am stuck...

Comment: Ok, so I messed up, sorry. I had used mediapath="{{path}}" instead of mediapath="path". Changed directive from @path to =path and everything is nice and clean. Sorry again, need to RTFM.

Answer (score 0):

You can call to a $scope function that returns the value.